# The import org.mockito.Mockito.lenient cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-boot

please i need a help

```
    lenient().when(moneyTransferService.validateName())
            .thenReturn(validatorName);
```

- The method lenient() is undefined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you added this config ?

```
Mockito.mockitoSession()
  .initMocks(this)
  .strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
  .startMocking();
```

Comment: check this link : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-unnecessary-stubbing-exception

Comment: add @BeforeEach method for exemple